# How to add/inject arbitrary Javascript to code that tmap_leaflet() generates?

Tags: leaflet, tmap, r-leaflet

Using the R's `tmap` package in "view" mode, here I have R pseudocode that generates an interactive world map, and adds an info-button that shows an alert using javascript.

```
# this is pseudocode - providing real data would be too much work
lf <- tmap_leaflet(tm_world) %>% 
        setView(2.2945, 0, zoom=2) %>% 
        addEasyButton(
            button = easyButton(
              icon = 'fa-warning',
              onClick = JS('function(btn, map){ alert("At very high zoom levels,\\nsite locations are approximate\\ndue to various issues."); }')
            )
          ) 
print(lf)
```

Now when `print.tmap()` and `save_tmap()` are called, they generate a complex HTML page with lots of javascript base64-encoded inside the page.

I want to include some of my javascript snippets (onLoad handlers, AMD modules) that end up as `script` tags in the `<head>` or `<footer>` elements, unlike the `onClick` handler of the `easyButton`).

How can I do that without editing the generated file manually after saving? I want to do this from within R.

Comment: I would be interested to hear how this turns out - there is a `tmap_leaflet` function, that produces a leaflet object, which could be accessed from within R, but I never saw it used in practice...

Comment: I've used `tmap_leaflet()`, but it has issues (Firefox hangs while rendering augmented map, Chrome doesn't) . And tmap_leaflet() does not allow to to put *arbitrary* Javascript in the page, only controls. -- For now I'm editing the exported file by hand, adding `<script>` tags in the footer.

Comment: oki, I am marking the question as favorite and waiting to see some brilliant answers rolling in :)